# Performance of non-primary-key queries on a fully replicated Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, replication, eventual-consistency

I have set up a fully-replicated, 3-node Cassandra cluster on a single machine using Docker containers, with the following status:

`Datacenter: dc_n1`
`=================`
`Status   Address     Load       Tokens   Owns    Host_ID  Rack`
`UN       172.18.0.3  83.98 MiB  256      100.0%  5bf      rack_n1`

`Datacenter: dc_n2`
`=================`
`Status   Address     Load       Tokens   Owns    Host_ID  Rack`
`UN       172.18.0.6  83.52 MiB  256      100.0%  0518     rack_n2`

`Datacenter: dc_n3`
`=================`
`Status   Address     Load       Tokens   Owns    Host_ID  Rack`
`UN       172.18.0.2  83.52 MiB  256      100.0%  ca95     rack_n3`

Now consider the following keyspace:

`create KEYSPACE stackoverflow WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc_n1':1,'dc_n2':1,'dc_n3':1};`

and a table defined as (let's assume T_notID is unique):

`create TABLE stackoverflow.TABLE (T_ID int PRIMARY KEY, T_notID int, T_Data text);`

When I dispatch a number (say, a hundred) of concurrent Java threads submitting the following two JDBC queries to Cassandra nodes (repeatedly, for a minute), I witness a 100X performance drop for (B) queries:

> (A) SELECT T_Data FROM TABLE WHERE T_ID = ?
>
> (B) SELECT T_Data FROM TABLE WHERE T_notID = ? ALLOW FILTERING

(B) queries also raise many Cassandra errors that:  `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ONE (timeout while waiting for repair of inconsistent replica)`:

I understand that, in general, usage of 'ALLOW FILTERING' in queries is an antipattern and should be used with extreme care, but in the simplified example above, since the data is **fully replicated** and one copy of each item resides at every node, I do not understand why PK-queries and nonPK-queries behave differently.

In other words, considering the fact that `read consistency` in this scenario is `ONE` and each node can respond to the queries without communicating with other nodes in the cluster (regardless of the primary key definition),  I would have expected similar behavior from Cassandra to a centralized SQL database.

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening and/or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have condition on the partition key - Cassandra knows where data is located on disk, and can jump to begin of partition and read the data sequentially.  But if you have condition on non-partition then your query will need to go through all data and filter out only necessary pieces - you don't have any indexes that will allow Cassandra to figure out where data is located.

If you need to run the query on the `T_notID` very often, then you can create materialized view or secondary index (but you need to understand what limitations they have).

DataStax has a [very good blog post](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2) about ALLOW FILTERING and where it could be used.